# Accessing browser elements from an XUL iframe

Tags: firefox-addon, xul, firefox-addon-sdk

I am developing an extension using the Add-on SDK and created an vbox that contains an iframe and appended the vbox to the main-window

Eg.

```
main-window
- my-vobx
-- my-iframe [src=Data.url('test.html')]
```

Is it possible to access any of the elements above the iframe from test.html?

Answer (score 1):

What is your use case, eg from your html content, what would you do with the xul nodes?

XUL Iframes are almost exactly like html iframes:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/XUL/iframe

You should probably use content scripts and message passing:

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/developers/docs/sdk/latest/dev-guide/guides/content-scripts/index.html